# remove any combinations of characters from vba string

Tags: vba, excel

I have a string value of ;00330508911=010403954? in Excel VBA
I would like to remove all characters except for the second set of digits, being 010402600.
I have tried many other alternatives with no luck, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify as `010402600` is not within `;00330508911=010403954?`.

Comment: Also post what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your question is 'how to strip out the number between the equals sign and the question mark', it's basic string manipulation:

```
Public Function secondNumber(inputStr As String) As String

    'text after the equals sign
    a = Mid(inputStr, InStr(1, inputStr, "=") + 1, 100)

    'and before the question mark
    b = Mid(a, 1, InStr(1, a, "?") - 1)

    secondNumber = b

End Function
```

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you so much for your help!